# Get number of seconds from a suffixed string

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, php-carbon

I want to be able to parse time specification from a human understandable format like:

- 2h
- 40s
- 50m
- 1d

Where d is the largest possible specification.

Is there a standard function in PHP (including Carbon or any part of Symfony) to parse such specifications, or should I implement it myself (fairly easy)

Comment: Neither strtotime, not Carbon::createFromDateString can handle this - tried myself, PHP 7+

Comment: In this context we speak about duration or Date/time... ? Because, even if you transcript this pattern to a standard date/timee format, the day value here wouldn't be treated as a day(24h). My advice If it's a regular pettern, you could make a php function that converts it to a standard format.

Comment: These aren't dates or times, they're *durations*. If anything, you'll want to look at [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php).

Comment: @deceze thanks, this is a partial solution that enabled me to create a fully working one

Comment: The syntax you use is handled out of the box by `CarbonInterval::fromString`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to deceze, I found this solution:

```
$timeLimit =  new \DateInterval('PT' . strtoupper($timeLimitString));
```

where 'PT' is the ISO prefix for time intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I think about custom function that can parse string and calculate time:

```
<?php

function str2time($input) {
    preg_match('/(\d+)(\D+)/', $input, $matches);

    switch ($matches[2]) {
        case 's':
        case 'sec':
            $time = (int)$matches[1];
        case 'm':
            $time = (int)$matches[1] * 60;
            break;
        case 'h':
            $time = (int)$matches[1] * 60 * 60;
            break;
        case 'd':
            $time = (int)$matches[1] * 60 * 60 * 24;
            break;          
        default:
            $time = 'wrong format';
    }
    
    return $time;
}

echo str2time('50m');
```

Test this code [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=92ba664c63663457a7b7f7c1fd44f91a&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Thanks, but custom code is something I wanted to avoid here.

Answer (score 1):

This is handled as interval in Carbon:
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-interval

```
CarbonInterval::fromString('2h 40s 50m 1d')
```